# Integer multiplication result is negative

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My multiplication of two positive integers results in a negative value and thus i cant calculate the sqrt but get a `math domain error`.
My variables can be of size 10^10 and higher.

```
sum = math.sqrt ( np.power( x , 2 ) * np.power( y , 2 ) )
```

Which dtype works for my needs or how else can i solve this?

**EDIT:**

The values are currently both (by accident the same) 59049. But as I said, they allready create the error and can get even higher. I can't give you a print because this is part of a calculation done in Django.

**EDIT 2:**

As correctly assumed in the comments the code should have been with `+` no `*`

```
d.sum = math.sqrt( np.power(d.active , 2) + np.power(d.passive , 2))
```

Some more background:
At one point of my Project I get a matrix and need to do the following calculations:

```
test = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
m = test
matrix= m.dot(m).dot(m).dot(m).dot(m)
activearray = matrix.sum(axis=1)
passivearray = matrix.sum(axis=0)

for idx, Descriptor.id in enumerate(projectdescriptors):
        d = Descriptor.objects.get(name=Descriptor.id)
        d.active = activearray[idx]
        d.passive = passivearray[idx]
        d.sum = math.sqrt( np.power(d.active , 2) + np.power(d.passive , 2))
        d.save()
```

Comment: What values are in x and y before this line? Could you add a print(x) and print(y) before to see what their values are before the error?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Can be simplified to `sum = a * b`

Comment: @MarkDickinson: except this is not hypot (as of now)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: True. I glanced at it and mistook the `*` for `+`. I can't help suspecting that `hypot` is what the OP actually wants, though.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: yep, I have that suspicion too.

Comment: You are absolutely right, my brain just took a brake while writing this...thanks. Can the error still occure when calculating with big numbers?

Comment: Can you give us more background on what the calculation is for?

Comment: I suspect you are running this on Windows, where the default numpy integer array has type `np.int32`.  Then `np.array([59049], dtype=np.int32)**2` gives `array([-808182895], dtype=int32)`.   That is, the integer calculation overflows and "wraps around" to negative values. Change `test` to an array of floating point values or `np.int64`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for because exactly this happened. With `dtype=np.int64` I got more room to work with. Is there any possibility to further increase the maximum value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments your problem is that the result is overflowing and becoming negative due to using integer variables.

The solution that should solve your issue should be to convert the numbers to floats (Before the operations do: `x=x.astype(np.float32)`) and then do the operations.

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([3,3E18])
y=np.array([4,4E18])
dtypes=[np.int64,np.float32]

for dt in dtypes:
    x=x.astype(dt)
    y=y.astype(dt)
    z2=x**2+y**2
    z=np.sqrt(z2)
    print("Result with "+str(dt)+"=",z2,z)
```

Result:

```
Result with <class 'numpy.int64'>= [                  25 -9051522149004607488] [ 5. nan]
Result with <class 'numpy.float32'>= [2.5e+01 2.5e+37] [5.e+00 5.e+18]
```